# How play an audio file with defined decibel values with windows API?

Tags: android, html, winapi, audio, windows-media-player

I have a use case where i need to play my audio file in a browser with different decibel value. I tried with HTML5 audio tag and could not able to see this feature available. So i want to go with Windows API.

I have seen some function like WaveoutWrite() for Wav file playing, but i want a generic function like there in android (AudioManager.SetVolume(LeftEarDecibel, RightEarDecibel);

Can anyone please suggest the best way of doing it?

Thanks & Regards,
Siva.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no concept of being able to set exact "decibels" in Windows(unless you mean the attenuation of the source), there are plenty of ways to control output volume of a process.  All of these volume controls are of course relative to the user's settings for device volume and whatever external speaker volume setting he has.

You likely want [ISimpleAudioVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends.